# How do I aggregate with group by in mysql withou setting sql mode?

Tags: mysql, group-by, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio, sql-mode

This query gets the output I want.  In order to run it I have to run

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

Because otherwise I get an error:

SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'knownLoss.t1.loss' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT 
  t1.klDate AS LDate
  , t1.Category
  , t1.reason AS Reason
  , sum(t1.loss) AS Loss
  , round(t1.loss / t2.loss,2) AS Percentage
FROM 
  deptkl t1
JOIN (
  SELECT 
      Store
    , sum(loss) AS loss
  FROM
    deptkl
  WHERE 
    klDate >= date_sub(SUBDATE(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate())), interval 7 day)
AND 
    klDate < SUBDATE(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()))
AND
    Store = 19
AND
    Department = 80
) t2 ON t1.Store = t2.Store

WHERE 
  klDate >= date_sub(SUBDATE(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate())), interval 7 day)
  AND 
  klDate < SUBDATE(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()))
  AND
  t1.Store = 19
AND
  Department = 80
GROUP BY
  klDate
, Category
, reason
```

When I place this into the Dataset and Query Dialog of Jasper Studio, I get the same error and I am unable to use the SET sql_mode = ''; command. Any thoughts?  If there is a way to achieve this without using SET sql_mode = '';?

Comment: What is the point of the subquery?

Comment: Please explain the logic behind the query and provide sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do this :

```
round(sum(t1.loss / t2.loss)/count(*),2)  AS Percentage
```

this will calculate the sum of the average loss for every records in the result then divide it on the the count of the record of the group it's like average of average.

EDITS:

> sorry i made a syntax error now ,it should give the th wanted result and the error is because you are  not using aggregate function on a column that is not in group by clause

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the error is from this line in your select:

```
round(t1.loss / t2.loss,2) AS Percentage
```

Since you `GROUP BY` clause does not include this column it's somewhat of a coin toss which `t1.loss` and `t2.loss` values will be used. In some cases those values happen to always be the same based on your criteria and so you get the correct results regardless, but the db will still complain since it's being asked to return somewhat arbitrary results for those columns.  One way to deal with this would be to simply apply an aggregate function to the columns in question like this:

```
round(min(t1.loss) / min(t2.loss),2) AS Percentage
```

or...

```
round(avg(t1.loss) / avg(t2.loss),2) AS Percentage
```

Comment: While this correctly explains the source of the error, the proposed solution may not be logically correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I agree but it's impossible to know without seeing the dataset.  I myself have run into this where the result of a given column is *always* the same in a `group by`, and in that case `min()` or `max()` will at least get rid of the error and still output the same results.  a better solution would probably be to adjust the `group by` clause - but only the author can determine this.

Comment: The OP shouldn't leave all of us guessing like this, but your logic seems as good as any guess right now.